# Fullcalendar resize doesn't work when height property is set

Tags: fullcalendar

The resize method of fullcalendar doesn't seem to work when the [height property](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/) is set. I have set the 'editable' property to true. I am getting the resize indicator, however, nothing happens when I try resizing it. Dragging of events to different timeslot is working. Here is my code:

```
window.calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: 'meetings/',
    header: false,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',      
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    lang: 'nl',
    minTime: '08:00:00',
    maxTime: '18:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayDefault: false,
    weekends: false,
    editable: true,
    columnFormat: {
        day: 'D dddd',
        week: 'D dddd'
    },
    axisFormat: 'H.mm',     
    loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },      
    eventDataTransform: function(eventdata){            
        var start = moment(eventdata.start);
        if (start._a[3] == 0){
            start.hour('8').minute('0').second('0');
        }
        eventdata.start = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");         
        var end = moment(eventdata.end);            
        if ((end._a && end._a[3] == 0) || !end._a){
            if (!end._a){
                end = moment(eventdata.start);
            }
            end.hour('17').minute('0').second('0');
        }
        eventdata.end = end.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        return eventdata;
    },      

});
```

**Edit:**
The problem only appears when the height is set programmatically, through:
    window.calendar.fullCalendar('option','height',700);

**Edit 2:**
I have found that when I resize an event, the window resize event is triggered.

Comment: try to give more explanation of question

Comment: @dennis when you try to resize does your browser console show any error?

Comment: @dennis if your problem is resolved, you can post the answer and mark your own answer as accepted answer, this will help future visitors to your question.

Comment: @Devjosh The marking as resolved was a bit premature. The console doesn't show any errors when I try to resize. I have found that the window resize event is fired when I try to resize an event.

Comment: @dennis are you setting the height of appointment or calendar itself?

Comment: @Devjosh I'm setting the height of the calendar itself. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/. Using the plain property works, but I want it to update when the window resizes, so I'm using the setter. However the setter is breaking the resize capability of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dennis,  i cant see any [eventResize](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventResize/) callback defined in your fullcalendar constructor, this is a callback which fires when you resize the event. please have a look at link i provided. i dont know how you are figuring out that resize is not working, because when you resize an event it must be handled in evenResize callback (which inturn will make a call to your serverside code) to update the attached datasource.

If you already handled the callback then there must be a syntax or javascript error. please try it with different browser consols ie. IE script debugger etc..

**EDIT** :- As per your comment you should apply height when resized in eventResize callback using jquery or javascript.
OR
[**arshaw**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/windowResize/) says that the fullcalendar should automatically adapt to the new size. IMHO you need not to set the height. not sure what your requirement is.

Comment: Okay Josh, I have set a simple callback that console.logs the event. It stops firing after I have set the height option through the setter:
    window.calendar.fullCalendar('option','height',(height-100));

Comment: Using the built in windowResize callback did the trick. Thanks Josh!

Comment: my pleasure helping you